# how to change retake and use photo buttons of UIImagePickerController with images

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

Am using camera in my app by using UIImagePickerController.I want to change the default Retake and UsePhoto buttons with images.How do i need to proceed to implement this.

Comment: You will have to write you own image picker and camera control as you can not change the default one.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your custom view with the buttons you want to show. When you create UIImagePickerController just set the following:

```
picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.showsCameraControls = NO;

self.overlayView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"OverlayView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
self.overlayView.frame = picker.cameraOverlayView.frame;

picker.cameraOverlayView = self.overlayView; //Overlay View will be your custom view.
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```